# How Local Database Cache works

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, caching

Does anyone know how Local Database Cache works?
Does it save the user's updates even when they close the software and/or computer and when online update it against the web database or closing the software without online connection means losing the changes?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882690.aspx) Local Database Cache you are asking about?

Comment: @idstam yes, that's the one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All reads and writes are done to your local database (on disk).

It will read / write the master database when you tell the application to synchronize the data.

Comment: Yes (as far as I can tell). I've only read part of the documentation, and know the involved parts, but I've never used it.